# What's wrong with my bookmarklet script that runs on windows 10 but not on Mac?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, code-snippets, bookmarklet

I just found the magic of snippets and bookmarklets scripts. It was a great thing! It worked!

I use Google Chrome on Windows 10. I found a code on the web and made some changes acording to my needs.
The code below works for bookmarklets (just copy and paste it all in the bookmark editing box) this way: Search anything on google (use long phrase or sentence), then click on the bookmarklet and it will prompt to enter a name for the file (if you want to download a CSV with the results), or, do not enter any name and click Accept and it will display the list of emphasized text in a new tab.

Amazing...
Now here's the problem, my friend created the bookmarklet and pasted the script, and it will not run on his Mac while it does on my Windows (that's the only difference i can see right now).
Any Ideas?

```
(function() {
console.clear();
const words = [];

function uniq(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

let selector = `#search em`;       
const found = document.querySelectorAll(selector);       
if (found.length > 0) {
    found.forEach((f) => {
        let text = f.textContent;                                                           
        if (text) {
            words.push(text);
        }
    });
}

console.log("%c LOWER CASE", "font-size:14px;font-weight:bold");
words.map(v => v.toLowerCase()).filter(uniq).map(v => console.log(v));    
console.log("%c ALL", "font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;");
words.filter(uniq).map(v => console.log(v));  

str = words.map(v => v.toLowerCase()).filter(uniq);
strhtml =  str.map(v => "<br/>" + v);

var fname = prompt("Enter a filename if you want to download (or leave it blank to display emphasized words in a New Tab only).","");

if (fname != null) {
    var newWindow = window.open();
    newWindow.document.write(strhtml);
    newWindow.document.close();

    if(typeof words.filter(uniq) === "object"){
        str = JSON.stringify(str, undefined, 2);
    }

    if (fname != "") {
        var blob = new Blob([str], {type: 'text/json'}),
            e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
            a    = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = fname + ".csv";
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':');
        e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        a.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
}
})();
```